# twitch java google spreadsheet

Tags: java, google-sheets, irc, twitch

Okay, here goes nothing, I've been working on a twitch bot for my channel for some time now, making stupid little functions and stuff just to keep me coding and learning new things. I've taken on a project that seems to have gotten very complicated for me. If you have been to twitch I'm sure you have seen a loyalty bot that gives digital play money for time spent in the channel, so I wanted to add that feature with a twist. rather then use a local spreadsheet or MySQL or something that I've never used before I wanted to use the Google docs API to update an online spreadsheet so that the information could be seen by my viewers without the need for constant chat spamming for how many currency they have. (if I've already made a huge mistake in the planning phase don't hesitate to send me in the right direction with this)

so the basics, I'm using Pircbot to create a chat bot for twitch (irc based chat system). I want only two columns for now A being usernames and B being currency.

So first plan was when people join the chat look to see if they are on the spread sheet already and add them if they are not there, then implement a system for every ten minutes pushing out a value++ to anyone who is in the chat.

so on join run a function, simple enough:

```
    @Override
    protected void onJoin(String channel, String sender, String login,     String hostname) {
   //attempt to add new person to the spread sheet if they are not already listed.
   //cells(0,0) (a,1)
   try {
       ss.addUser(sender);
   }catch (IOException w) {
       System.out.println(w);
   }
   catch (ServiceException q){
       System.out.println(q);
   }
```

now comes the part I'm getting really lost on, I can't seem to figure out if this is working, but I have a strong feeling the code I found and was following is old and no longer right. here is the class for handling the spread sheet:

```
    class ss{

public static final String GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_USERNAME = "xxxx@gmail.com";
public static final String GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD = "xxxx";
public static final String SPREADSHEET_URL = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/"code after my sheet"";

public static void addUser(String user) throws IOException, ServiceException {
    /** Our view of Google Spreadsheets as an authenticated Google user. */
    SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("Print Google Spreadsheet Demo");

    // Login and prompt the user to pick a sheet to use.
    service.setUserCredentials(GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_USERNAME, GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD);

    // Load sheet
    URL metafeedUrl = new URL(SPREADSHEET_URL);
    SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = service.getEntry(metafeedUrl, SpreadsheetEntry.class);

    URL listFeedUrl = ((WorksheetEntry) spreadsheet.getWorksheets().get(0)).getListFeedUrl();

    // Creating a local representation of the new row.
    ListEntry row = new ListEntry();
    row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("Name", user);
    row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("Currency", "0");
}
```

}

as you can see, I got as for as trying to add new users as they enter the channel, but unfortunately all it does is throw errors:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetService
at ss.addUser(didbot.java:30)
at didbot.onJoin(didbot.java:186)
at org.jibble.pircbot.PircBot.handleLine(PircBot.java:1000)
at org.jibble.pircbot.InputThread.run(InputThread.java:92)
```

total code if you are brave enough to see the mass text wall of my failure in coding xD

```
import org.jibble.pircbot.PircBot;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Date;
import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetService;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.WorksheetEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.*;
import com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException;





/**
 * Created by Evan on 11/4/2014.
 */
 class ss{

    public static final String GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_USERNAME = "*email*@gmail.com"; // Fill in google account username
    public static final String GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD = "*password*"; // Fill in google account password
    public static final String SPREADSHEET_URL = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/*code*"; // Fill in google spreadsheet URI

    public static void addUser(String user) throws IOException, ServiceException {
        /** Our view of Google Spreadsheets as an authenticated Google user. */
        SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("Print Google Spreadsheet Demo");

        // Login and prompt the user to pick a sheet to use.
        service.setUserCredentials(GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_USERNAME, GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD);

        // Load sheet
        URL metafeedUrl = new URL(SPREADSHEET_URL);
        SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = service.getEntry(metafeedUrl, SpreadsheetEntry.class);

        //Here we are working with worksheet 0, if you have multiple worksheet, then change this value to get the corresponding worksheet
        URL listFeedUrl = ((WorksheetEntry) spreadsheet.getWorksheets().get(0)).getListFeedUrl();

        // Creating a local representation of the new row.
        ListEntry row = new ListEntry();
        row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("Name", user);
        row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal("Credits", "0");


        // Sending the new row for insertion into worksheet.

    }
}

public class didbot extends PircBot {


    public didbot() {
        this.setName("didbot");
        ClassExecutingTask executingTask = new ClassExecutingTask();
        executingTask.start();


    }

    public class ClassExecutingTask {

        long delay = 10 * 1000; // 600000 = 10 minutes
        LoopTask task = new LoopTask();
        Timer timer = new Timer("TaskName");

        public void start() {
            timer.cancel();
            timer = new Timer("TaskName");
            Date executionDate = new Date(); // no params = now
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, executionDate, delay);
        }

        public void addCredits (String veiwer, int a){

        }

        private class LoopTask extends TimerTask {
            public void run() {
                //add credits here to add one credit every 10 minutes

                //sendMessage(channel, sender + ", thank you for checking out the channel!");


                //  getUsers("");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(String channel, String sender, String login, String hostname, String message) {
      /*  if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("time")) {
            String time = new java.util.Date().toString();
            sendMessage(channel, sender + ": The time is now " + time);
        }*/
        if (message.contains("!songrequest ")) {
            String songRequest = message.substring(13);
            if (!songRequest.isEmpty()) {
                try {

                    PrintStream srout = new PrintStream("C:/Users/songRequest.txt");
                    srout.println(songRequest);
                    System.out.println(songRequest);
                    srout.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        }

    }
   @Override
    protected void onJoin(String channel, String sender, String login, String hostname) {
    //attempt to add new person to the spread sheet if they are not already listed.
       //cells(0,0) (a,1)
       try {
           ss.addUser(sender);
       }catch (IOException w) {
           System.out.println(w);
       }
       catch (ServiceException q){
           System.out.println(q);
       }

      //  getUsers("");
    }

}
```

Comment: Well I appreciate you separating the wall of text from the actual problem. Could you link us to the necessary jar files to get this code running (if possible)?

Comment: well, I can, but that requires a few libraries of imports and it required me removing the authentication information, or making new dummy accounts and re-entering it, I guess I could just super simplify my question.

Comment: Is there a way I can use java to update an online spread sheet that has one column for usernames and one column for a number that I read and write from in real time? or is it so much easier to use an on machine database that I would be crazy to make it more difficult?